# Jtable refresh when delete a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a a table that show all book list from a txt file correctly.
I add a new button to frame that when get id number an its textfield and if found, delete it record from file, but if i want to delete from table too, i shoud redisplay the table frame.
I want to, when a record deleted from file, my table automatically refresh itself and no need to redisplay table frame.
my code is this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ReadBookFileToListM {

public ReadBookFileToListM(){
   final ReadBookFileToList rbftl=new ReadBookFileToList();
   final JFrame Bframe=new JFrame("All Book List");
  final JTextField tf1=new JTextField("             ");
  final JLabel foundlable=new JLabel();
    JButton button1=new JButton("Back To Main Page");
    JButton button2=new JButton("Exit");
    JButton button3=new JButton("Delete Book");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Bframe.setVisible(false);
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });


    JTable Btable=new JTable(rbftl);

    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean find=false;
    String Bookid=tf1.getText();
    File Mf=new File("D:\\AllBookRecords.txt");
    File Tf=new File("D:\\Boutput.txt");
    try{
        FileReader Bfr=new FileReader(Mf);
        BufferedReader Bbr=new BufferedReader(Bfr);
        PrintWriter Bpw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Tf));
        String Bs;
        while( (Bs=Bbr.readLine()) != null ){
                String[] Ust=Bs.split("   ");
                String Bname=Ust[0];
                String Bdate=Ust[1];
                String id=Ust[2];
            if(id.equals(Bookid.trim())){
                find=true;
                foundlable.setText("Book Found,    "+ Bname + "  " + Bdate);
            }
            if(!id.equals(Bookid.trim())){
                Bpw.println(Bs);
            }
        }
        Bpw.close();
        Bbr.close();
        Mf.delete();
        Tf.renameTo(Mf);

    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        foundlable.setText("File Not Found");
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        foundlable.setText("IO Error");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        rbftl.fireTableDataChanged();
        if(find)
        foundlable.setText("Book Deleted");
        else
            foundlable.setText("Book Not Found!");
            tf1.setText("     ");
    }
        }
    });

    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(Btable);
    button1.setToolTipText("To Go Main Page, Click here");
    button2.setToolTipText("Terminate Program");
    panel.add(sp);
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);
    panel.add(tf1);
    panel.add(foundlable);
    Bframe.add(panel);
    Btable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    Bframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Bframe.setBounds(300, 60, 550, 550);
    Bframe.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new ReadBookFileToListM();
}
  }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

addNotify() method JTable object may be useful, as it reconfigure enclosing scrollpane.

Just add `tableName.addNotify()` after you delete row in table.

Comment: I don't understand what it is meant by "Reconfigure enclosing scroll pane" ?

Answer (score 3):

given that you can determine which row is to be removed, you can use the following,

[`AbstractTableModel#fireTableRowsDeleted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)

and then, if needed, issue a repaint request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to delete a row from a table?

If so, you should just delete the row from your `TableModel` and fire the appropriate table changed event to let the table know that you've deleted the row

Comment: Um, it's the fundamentals of using a JTable.  I recommend you read the Sun tutorials on JTables - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html